# How can I print the random list of grades without copying the same grade of the other students?

Tags: python

I am having a trouble on how can I print the grades of the students using random package without copying the same grade of the other students. The program requires functions to make. please help

```
import random


def get_values():
    list = []
    q = 1
    i = 4
    for num in range(i):
        data = random.randint(1, 100)
        list.append(data)
        #print("Quiz no.", q)
        #print(data)
        q += 1

    return list


def validate(ctr):
    while ctr > 50:
        print("Maximum of 50 students only")
        exit()
    return ctr


def grade(x):
    FG = sum(x) / 4
    return FG


def EQ(FG):
    if FG < 60:
        s = float(5.0)
        print(s)

    elif FG >= 60 and FG < 75:
        s = float(3.0)
        print(s)

    elif FG >= 75 and FG < 90:
        s = float(2.0)
        print(s)

    elif FG >= 90 and FG <= 100:
        s = float(1.0)
        print(s)

    return s


def main():
    list_high = []
    list_low = []
    ls=[]
    repeat = 'Y'
    ctr = 1
    while repeat.upper() == 'Y':
        validate(ctr)
        x = get_values()
        y = grade(x)
        z = EQ(y)
        high = list_high.append(max(x))
        low = list_low.append(min(x))

        print("Student #  Quiz 1     Quiz2    Quiz 3    Quiz4    Grade      EQ")
        q = 1

        for num in range(ctr - 1):
            print("\n   ", q, end='')

            for c in range(len(x)):
                print("       ", x[c], end="")
            q += 1
            print("    ", y, "    ", z, end=" ")

        ctr += 1

       # average_high = sum(list_high) / len(list_high)
        #average_low = sum(list_low) / len(list_low)


        repeat = input("\n Enter Y to input another students score: ")



main()
```

the output of my program

Student #  Quiz 1     Quiz2    Quiz 3    Quiz4    Grade      EQ

```
1        17        95        5        92     52.25      5.0 
2        17        95        5        92     52.25      5.0 
3        17        95        5        92     52.25      5.0 
4        17        95        5        92     52.25      5.0 
5        17        95        5        92     52.25      5.0 
6        17        95        5        92     52.25      5.0
```

Enter Y to input another students score:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're overthinking it. Also, try to iterate over a collection of objects rather than a range-based for-loop, if you can.

Here is something that might be helpful:

```
def main():
    from random import sample

    number_of_quizzes = 4

    scores = sample(range(1, 100), number_of_quizzes)
    print(scores)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Output:

```
[10, 93, 66, 46]
>>>
```

Then, if you have, for example, five students, and each student has four quizzes, you can extend it like so:

```
def main():
    from random import sample

    number_of_students = 5
    number_of_quizzes = 4

    for current_scores in (sample(range(1, 100), number_of_quizzes) for _ in range(number_of_students)):
        print(current_scores)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Output:

```
[25, 82, 87, 13]
[91, 12, 76, 65]
[96, 90, 19, 34]
[82, 67, 4, 8]
[6, 91, 47, 68]
>>>
```

EDIT - This is closer to what you've written:

```
 def get_random_scores():
    from random import randint

    number_of_scores = 4
    scores = []

    for _ in range(number_of_scores):
        score = randint(1, 100)
        scores.append(score)
    return scores

def get_highest_score_for_quiz_n(students_scores, *, n):
    return max(list(zip(*students_scores))[n-1])


def main():

    number_of_students = 5
    students_scores = []
    for _ in range(number_of_students):
        students_scores.append(get_random_scores())

    print("The scores are:")
    for scores in students_scores:
        print(scores)

    max_third_quiz_score = get_highest_score_for_quiz_n(students_scores, n=3)
    print(f"The highest score on the third quiz was {max_third_quiz_score}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: is there another way to make it? like using of the basic algorithm because our teacher requires us to use only the basic code